# ST_Intersect returns with double result

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to write case statement to intersect point in areas using Postgres as below:

```
SELECT Point.id, Point.geom, Box.Postcode,
CASE
    WHEN ST_Intersects(Box.geom, Point.geom) AND Box.postcode = 'A' THEN 'A'
    WHEN ST_Intersects(Box.geom, Point.geom) AND Box.postcode = 'B' THEN 'B'
    WHEN ST_Intersects(Box.geom, Point.geom) AND Box.postcode = 'C' THEN 'C'
    ELSE 'No postcode'
END AS PointPostcode
```

The idea is that every Point which is located inside the Box will have a new attribute column named 'PointPostCode' and have postcodes information: 'A','B','C' depends on their locations. And for the point located outside the box will have information 'No postcode'.

I run those queries successfully, I also got the new column as what I want. The points located inside the Box also have the postcode information correctly but at the sametime it is also given 'No postcode' label for all point (re-double the value).

Could someone help me to figure it out where is the mistake of my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to execute following query:

```
SELECT Point.id, Point.geom, Box.Postcode,
CASE
    WHEN Box.postcode = 'A' THEN 'A'
    WHEN Box.postcode = 'B' THEN 'B'
    WHEN Box.postcode = 'C' THEN 'C'
    ELSE 'No postcode'
END AS PointPostcode
WHERE ST_Intersects(Box.geom, Point.geom)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get some reading on query syntax, identifier names and `JOINS`; for instance

- you don't specify relations (`FROM`) and their join conditions; you likely want a `LEFT JOIN`, or your `CASE` won't make any sense, since no rows outside of any `box.geom` will be selected
- PG uses `lower_case` identifier names when not explicitly wrapped in `"`; i.e. `BoxPostcode = boxpostcode = BoXpOsTcOdE` (if a column *was* created with 'special' characters, it's also `"BoxPostcode" != BoxPostcode`)

With that in mind, using `COALESCE` is a more generic and performant way:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p."Postcode",
       COALESCE(b."Postcode", 'No postcode') AS "BoxPostcode",
       p.geom
FROM   "Point" AS p
LEFT JOIN
       "Box" AS b
ON     ST_Intersects(b.geom, p.geom)
;
```

Comment: I just realized this is an ancient question...hope it can shed some light on things, nonetheless.